# Retrieve subset of string Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have the following sting:

```
2016-12-13T14:31:00+0100
```

and I would like to only have

```
14:31:00
```

I tried it with

```
replace("*/T.*/+", "");
```

But this doesnt work.

Does somebody now how to setup the replace function of Javascript correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) with the right paramters for a standard [ISO 6801](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) combined date and time string.

```js
var string = '2016-12-13T14:31:00+0100',
    time = string.slice(11, 19);

console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the date part and replace it as

```
str = "2016-12-13T14:31:00+0100".replace(/.*T(.*)\+.*/, '$1')
console.log(str)
// "14:31:00"
```

- `.*T` matches anything till `T`
- `(.*)\+` Matches anything till the next `+` and captures in `$1`

---

If you are sure of the input string, you can even split the string on `T` and `+` as

```
"2016-12-13T14:31:00+0100".split(/[T+]/)[1]
// "14:31:00
```

Comment: Replace is bad in this context as it will introduce side-effect and alter the original value.

Comment: @JuhaTauriainen It doesn't alter the orginal string, It returns a new string

Answer (score 0):

If the "T" and the "+" are always there, it's easy:

```
var split = "2016-12-13T14:31:00+0100".split ( "T" );
var final = split [ 1 ].split ( '+' ) [ 0 ];
```

If those aren't consistent, then you do something more involved, probably like this:

```
var split = "2016-12-13T14:31:00+0100".split ( ':' );
var stringPart1 = split[0].substring ( split[0].length - 2 );
// We can just use split [ 1 ], the second part, as-is
var stringPart3 = split[2].split ( '+' ) [ 0 ];
var finalString = stringPart1 + ":" + split [ 1 ] + ":" + stringPart3;
```

Checked it, both work, and you can see how the second example could let you accommodate different cases as to how you get and format your string parts.

Note that slicing seems like a good idea, but will only work if the length of the string is always consistent. Regex is also a possibility, but regex can be so cryptic to me, probably a shortcoming I should remedy some day.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `replace`:

```js
var s = "2016-12-13T14:31:00+0100";
var n = s.replace(/([\d\-]+T)|(\+\d+)/g, "");
console.log(n);
```

`([\d\-]+T)` matches the date

`(\+\d+)` matches the timezone

`g` means find all matches (global)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
    var s = "2016-12-13T14:31:00+0100" 
    var a = s.split(":")
      a[0]= a[0].slice(a[0].length - 2)
      a[2] = a[2].slice(0,2)
    var res = a.join(":")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also do like

```js
var res = "2016-12-13T14:31:00+0100".match(/[^T]+(?=\+)/)[0];
console.log(res);
```